# Laravel 8 and mysql quote problems

Tags: php, mysql

Laravel or mysql is not sending the quotes in the mysql query.

Follow print as evidence.

[image]

This is happening on the production machine, because in development it is ok.

[image]

I don't understand how the Text is going without the quotes for mysql.

Product and test machine configuration is the same.

- Laravel 8
- Mysql 8

Comment: Don't post images of text

Comment: What do you mean???

Comment: The quotes won't show up in a parameterized query's output like `SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE account = adm limit 1`. It's not broken, it's just handled by the parameterization system. Your error isn't from the quoting.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is a "2002 php_network_getaddresses" as it is a connection issue and nothing really related to your code.

Verify your database configuration and that it is accessible from php process/user.